# What is the term for the white foam of the wave apart from sea/ocean foam?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

The closest term to what I want to know is, so far, 'Swash'.
But not exactly, because it is a term for 'wave' not ...the foam/the frothy part of the wave. I want to know if there is a term for that white part of the swash. Like, when a wave gently breaks on the shore or hits with a rock and then there's the white froth happening. I'm sorry I feel like I am rambling now;
 (Or...maybe Whitecapping? But it seems to me that is also just a description of another wave form, bah..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Foam" is the simplest word to use, "Ocean foam" or "[Sea foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_foam)" if the context doesn't allow the word "sea" to be dropped.

> Two boys were playing in the foam on the beach.

Foam produced on waves far from the beach by strong winds are called "White horses"

> The wind picked up in the afternoon, and the sea became covered in white horses.

Comment: White horses sounds poetic, good to know~! I searched the images of sea/ocean foam and they all somewhat..dramatic or too bubbly(?) so I thought maybe there's another term for the gentle form of sea foam. Thank you for the reply with the examples!  +Oh, how about the 'wave froth' ?? Is it common to say that to describe what I questioned, too? Sea/ocean foam = wave froth ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is really going on within the OP's mind (Ugh sorry). but it is definately the [**Sea Foam.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_foam)

Please refer to the Wiki page, I can not say anymore.

> Sea foam, ocean foam, beach foam, or spume is a type of foam **created by the agitation of seawater,**

Comment: The first word I thought of when I saw the title was 'spume'.

Comment: I was rambling, sorry about that :') I thought that if maybe there is some less agitated(?) shape of sea foam that has its own term. But clearly foam is just that, foam. Thank you for answering my question~.

Comment: @longne I don't know if this wave is more "agitated" or less "agitated", but may be the word "sea spray" could be the substitution? link [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_spray ]. Looks like a big foam that does not contact  with the shore or stones.